# Capital letter for competition names?

Tags: orthography, capitalization

I was writing recently, and wanted to reference a competition managed by the Economist Intelligence Unit. It's called the "Global Liveability Rating".

First of all, should I capitalize the name of the competition? Second of all, is "liveability" even a word? Spell-check deems it an error almost universally.

Comment: Spell-check is exactly that: a spell *check*. It does not determine whether a word is incorrectly spelled or not, or whether a word exists or not; it alerts *you* the author or editor to *check* that it is and it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should capitalize Global Liveability Rating, as it is [a title](http://www.eiu.com/public/topical_report.aspx?campaignid=liveability2014) for something. If the name is turned into an acronym (GLR), then you should definitely capitalize each initial letter of each word of the acronym.

Yes, *liveability* actually a word. It is the [British spelling of the American *Livability*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/liveable).